# Can I use VSYS output on NPM1100 as input to another regulator?

Tags: batteries, power-electronics, design, low-power, nordic

After designing a power system around an [NPM1100](https://www.nordicsemi.com/products/npm1100) PMIC, we noticed that as our lipo battery decreases to around 3.55 V, the regulation out 3.0 V starts to drop (see graph below). We do have a sensitive circuit downstream that needs a stable 3.0 V out over the cycle of the lipo. Looking at the datasheet it does indicate a drop out voltage of ~0.41 V depending on load current. Isn't this rather high for a low power PMIC?

[image: Voutb vs Vbat for npm1100]

For a quick fix without changing any components, would it be sufficient to add a 3V0 regulator with a better dropout to the VSYS output pin of the NPM1100? I attached a proposal for the circuit below. The sensitive circuit will consume at peak about 70 mA at 3.0 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffVqCy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there is no issue doing this. It works out rather nicely since I can use the additional regulator as a load switch to that circuit. Of course an ideal solution would be to use a better PMIC, but this was least effort.